# Complex analysis exam question - A converging sum of series with positive real parts is absolute convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

This is a question I was given at the last exam, trying to understand it to help me with the next one.

We're given a series $z_k=|z_k|e^{ia_k}$ and there exists $0<\alpha<\pi/2$ such that $|a_k|<\alpha$ for all k
Assume $\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}z_k$ converge and prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}|z_k|$ converge.

Now I understand that $Re({z_k})>0$ because of the given data about the angles, but is there something stronger that helps me prove this?

I am really interested in hearing a hint and not a complete solution.

Thank you,
Chaim

Comment: Your angle condition also tells you something about $\operatorname{Im} z_k$. Together with the absolute convergence of the real parts (since those are non-negative), the absolute convergence follows.

Comment: In this situation, $|z_k|$ is bounded by a constant multiple of $Re(z_k)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  is $Im z_k$ bounded? is that what you mean?

Comment: It is bounded, but that doesn't suffice. Can you see how $\tan\alpha$ might be relevant?

Comment: $|Im {z_k}|<=(Re {z_k})*tan\alpha$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the series $\sum z_k$ converges, its real part $\sum \mathrm{Re }\,  z_k$ must converge as well.

Furthermore $\mathrm{Re}\, z_k = |z_k| \cos a_k \geq |z_k| \cos \alpha$.

Thus the series $\sum |z_k|$ is bounded by the series with nonnegative terms $\sum \frac{1}{\cos \alpha} \mathrm{Re} \, z_k$, and it therefore must converge as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got that:

As i said $Rez_k>0$ for all k.

We can show that |$Im(z_k)|<=tan\alpha*Re(z_k)$
and because $|z|<=|Rez|+|Imz|$ we get that $|z_k|<=(1+tan\alpha)Re(z_k)$

Now all needs to be done is show that $\sum Re(z_k)$ converge.

@DanielFisher and @user180040 , Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, if $\sum z_k$ converges, then $\sum \operatorname{Re} z_k$ also converges because ...

Comment: Okay, that's correct. But I would have used the inequality $|z_k| < (\mathrm{Re} z_k)/\cos \alpha$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know the answer :) Should I give a full answer? I thought to leave it as an exercise...

Comment: @user180040 you are right :)

Comment: I think in the current situation, a full answer wouldn't spoil it for the OP ;) But it's your choice.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the right way to get Re in Latex?

Comment: @user180040 I just write Re

Comment: @user180040 `\operatorname{Re}`. Generally, you can right-click on math equations, and choose "Show as .. TeX commands" to see how it is obtained.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 0):

Note that,

$\text{Re}(z_k)=|z_k|\cos(a_k)$ and   $\text{Im}(z_k)=|z_k|\sin(a_k)$.

Get $$|z_k|\leq |z_k| + |z_k|\tan(a_k).$$

Get information about the $\tan(a_k)$ and use the fact that $\sum\text{Re}(z_k)<\infty$ and

$\sum\text{Im}(z_k)<\infty$.